# Cast to date failed when using findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I'm receiving a CastError on my date field within the 'Update' section of findOneAndUpdate(). I've created the below test to represent the problem. From my understanding, '2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z' should be a valid format to cast & update via Mongoose. I've found a wide array of similar SO posts, and converted my initial variables to various formats using moment.js, but it seems like a basic ISO string like the above should in fact work.

I've tried adjusting to $lte, converting to Date outside the findOneAndUpdate(), using YYYY-MM-DD format, parsing to int first, etc. but am truly floored by what I could be missing. Apologies if this is incredibly obvious.

const updatedT = B.findOneAndUpdate(

```
      //filter
      {
       //Using the below syntax in find() works perfectly
         "b_date" : {"$gte": new Date(bDateOrig)},
        'b_type':bTypeOrig,


     },
     //update
     {
        //Using the below results in CastError
        //if I comment the b_date line out, code runs as expected
       'b_date' : {"$gte": new Date('2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z')},
      'b_type':bTypeNew,

    },
    //options
    {new:true}
)
```

In summary - I'm hoping to understand if there are any nuances to consider when updating a Date - ex. what is the correct format for:

"$gte": new Date('2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z')

I'd be happy to provide further detail - thanks so much for reading!

Comment: can you try removing new Date from $gte line

Comment: Hey - thanks for taking a look, same error unfortunately; it'd also concern me attempting to upload a raw string as my model expects type Date

Comment: try the last part precision to 2 not 3 , e.g. 2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z should say 2018-10-03T14:07:03.38Z

Comment: appreciate the thought - still got the same error after updating to "$gte": new Date('2018-10-03T14:07:03.38Z')

Comment: try it like  "$gte": new ISODate('2018-10-03T14:07:03.38Z')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) is query operator but you used it in update.

Second, your `b_date` field has type `Date` so it will try to convert the whole `{"$gte": new Date('2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z')}` to `Date`. That causes the CastError.

Comment: Apologies for the basic error; removing gte worked - thank you for the help, I'll follow up on the docs